# How to make incremental value changes deriving values from a cell in Google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Need to create a cell (let's call it A1) that's value is decreased when value is added to another cell (let's call it B2)

This is the most basic function possible being `=sum(-B2)`

But I want the amount it subtracts for each unit added to B2 to increase by 1 every 3 numbers. Here's what I mean:

| Rank | Cost |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1(1) |
| 2 | 1(2) |
| 3 | 1(3) |
| 4 | 2(5) |
| 5 | 2(7) |
| 6 | 2(9) |
| 7 | 3(12) |
| 8 | 3(15) |
| 9 | 3(18) |

So if I put 15 into B2 it will actually decrease A1 by 45 instead of 15. How can I do this?

sample sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1509M3VqVyKFv5CnYm01hzUyUxe0-Cci0wJ8XfPKBmuk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: This is an instance where it is better to SHOW than to try to TELL. I encourage you to set up a sample spreadsheet with realistic data filling 5 or 10 rows. Manually enter into that sheet what the expected results would be, placed in the exact range where you'd like a formula to produce those results. Be sure, when you create the link, to set the permission to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor" so that those here can access the sheet, test approaches, and leave any solutions for you.

Comment: If you say so..

Comment: You mentioned something about putting 15 into cell B2 and getting 45 subtracted from something in Column A. I don't see that illustrated in your sheet. You mentioned numbers in Column A decreasing somehow, which I don't see happening in your sheet. I also see that your values shown in B11 and C11 jump by 4 only ONCE (instead of three times like everything before that point) before jumping to 5. This doesn't match what you describe in your post either. Please fully show in your sheet a set of realistic data in Columns A and B, and then manually enter what you want the results to be.

Answer (score 1):

Added a ridiculous formula to the sheet that should solve your problem, e.g. for the first value in A2:

`=A2*(((((A2-1)/3)+1-MOD((A2-1),3)/3)+1)/2-IF(MOD(A2,3)=0,0,MOD(A2,3)/3*(A2-MOD(A2,3))/(A2*MOD(A2,3)^2)))`

The general gist is that we try to find the average of the multipliers for the numbers that come before it, then offset the result by whatever fraction of 3 remains. The if-statement is because we have an N%3 value in the offset divisor, so we skip that for clean multiples of 3.

What a silly way to spend the evening :)

Comment: Amazing. If I wanted to modify to say, increase by 1 every 4 numbers or increase by 2 each time, how would I do that?

Comment: To increase by 1 every 4 numbers, just replace all the "3"s with "4". Increasing by 2 each time you'd probably have to add a multiplier of 2 everywhere you're dividing by 3. I'll have to leave that one as an exercise to the reader :)